# HTML: Select a class by screen size (Bootstrap). Fixing footer size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a web and mobile footers. So the thing is that my footer elements flew away if the screen size is too small, so I used bootstrap in-built xs,sm,md,lg,xl classes to display a footer by a screen size. So now I have one thing left which is to set footer height by screen size. For example if screen size is equal to xl - height should be 350px. If screen size is equal to sm the height should be 250px. And also I need to change the body margin-bottom too, how can I do this?

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
}
body {
     margin-bottom: 250px;
}
```

This is my footer for web users:

[image: a]

- As you can see it fits well for web users.

And this is my footer for mobile users.

[image]

- As you can see I need to change the footer height to fix the design issue.

Comment: did you try to delete `margin-bottom` for body?

Comment: you can use both `@media` for the mobile resolution or delete `margin-bottom` for the body.  because you use `position: absolute`  your footer is floating on your body therefor in mobile resolution a 250px  margin is appear.

Comment: But you can see I still need to change the height of the footer

Comment: did you try to use `@media` for mobile resolution? I need to see both your HTML and CSS.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UpTts2Bq This is HTML

Comment: don't you upload your website anywhere? what you upload right now is not contain CSS.

Comment: let's continue it in the chat. so maybe I can connect remotely to your computer and help.
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218680/room-for-mkafiyan-and-dzitc